# mysql replace string + next one char

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

Is it possible to `REPLACE` a string + next character in MySQL? Something like `LIKE` underscore.

For example, if `text` column is this:
`12 13 14 14_B 15 14_A`, `REPLACE` all `14_*` with an empty character, and replaced text should be:
`12 13 14 15`

Comment: job for regualr expressions possibly.

Comment: Could you refine or elaborate on your example. It is unclear how you arrived at the *result*.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: result means replaced text (final text).. edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll be looking to do this using a regular expression UDF in MySQL.  Key ingredients are

1. regular expression UDF - [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)
2. The regular expression itself

If you will **ONLY** ever see 2 to 4 of these that you need replaced, a poor man's working approach ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c5b6/7/0)):

```
SELECT *,IF(LOCATE('14_',B)+3<=Length(B),
         INSERT(B,LOCATE('14_',B),4,''),B) C
FROM
(
  SELECT *,IF(LOCATE('14_',A)+3<=Length(A),
           INSERT(A,LOCATE('14_',A),4,''),A) B
  FROM (
    SELECT *,IF(LOCATE('14_',x)+3<=Length(X),
             INSERT(X,LOCATE('14_',x),4,''),X) A
    FROM X
  ) Q1
) Q2
```

I've only catered for 3 replacements but you can easily expand the pattern.  Include only the columns from the base table needed in the outermost query.